# Android: How to show a dialog after user clicks "Okay" on a previous dialog

Tags: android, dialog

How come the AlertDialog that has the title "Location was saved to file" doesn't show up?  It is the one that should be displayed after the user presses Okay on the first dialog.

I think it has something to do with threads, but I'm not sure.

```
       SimpleDateFormat timeStampFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMMM-dd-yyyy");


        final EditText input = new EditText(EncounterActivity.this);
        input.setWidth(75);
        input.setText("Bear-Encounter-GPS-" + timeStampFormat.format(new Date()) + ".txt");

        new AlertDialog.Builder(EncounterActivity.this)
        .setTitle("Save GPS Location")
        .setMessage("Please enter a filename")
        .setView(input)
        .setIcon(R.drawable.gps)
        .setPositiveButton("Save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                try { 
                    File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                    if (root.canWrite()){
                        File fn = new File(root, input.getText().toString());
                        FileWriter gpxwriter = new FileWriter(fn);
                        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(gpxwriter);
                        out.write(ll.toUTMRef().toString());
                        out.close();



                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(EncounterActivity.this);
                        builder.setIcon(R.drawable.gps);
                        builder.setTitle("Location was saved to file");
                        builder.setMessage("Your GPS coordinates were saved to " + fn.getAbsolutePath())
                               .setPositiveButton("Okay", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                                   }
                               });
                        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                        alert.show();

                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    //ProfitBandit.alert(Shipment.this, "Couldn't write the file.");
                    Log.v("IOException", "Could not write file " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                // Do nothing.
            }
        }).show();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You CAN display an alert dialog from an alert dialog if you use the pattern showDialog(int) getInstanceSomeDialog and onCreateDialog(int) for both dialogs. So in my aboutAlertDialog I have:

```
    builder.setPositiveButton("View EULA", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {               //cancels itself?
        showDialog(DIALOG_EULA_SHOW);
    }       
});
```

which in turn displays an EULA in yet another AlertDialog. OR you could just toss up a Toast as in:

```
Toast.makeText(Main.this,"Location Saved.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

where Main is the activity class.